# Why exactly 0.09f - 0.01f == 0.0800000057f?

Tags: c#, floating-point, ieee-754

I know that floating point variable stores the number in a sign-exponent-fraction format (as it's stated in the IEEE 754), it's never precise and I should probably never compare two floats without specifying the precision.

But why exactly 0.09f - 0.01f gives you the value of 0.0800000057f? What exactly happens in under the hood of the .NET VM and in the memory when I do that subtraction?

Comment: Have you looked at the *exact* values of 0.09f and 0.01f to start with? See  http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx and find the DoubleConverter code there to see the exact values. Then the subtraction result probably won't be a surprise.

Answer (score 2):

`0.09` is represented as `00111101101110000101000111101100` in ieee-754, which is closest to the decimal value of `0.09000000357627869`

`0.01` is represented as `00111100001000111101011100001010` in ieee-754, which is closest to the decimal value of `0.009999999776482582`

Their subtraction yields `00111101101000111101011100001011` which is closest to the decimal value of `0.08000000566244125`

You can see how the actual subtraction is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766237/how-to-subtract-ieee-754-numbers)