# How can I subtract IEEE 754 numbers?

Tags: math, floating-point, ieee-754

I want to know how to subtract IEEE 754 numbers so I searched about this and found this answer: [How to subtract IEEE 754 numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766237/how-to-subtract-ieee-754-numbers), and it works fine with all the examples I've tried, except when I substract one, the number 1 have a lot of 0's in the mantissa, so by this logic a number should stay the same when I substract 1 to it?

PS: It would be the same for any number - 2^something, the mantissa would be full of 0's.

Someone explain pls

Answer (score 1):

When an IEEE 754 number is stored, it uses a very memory-efficient method.

All numbers except for very very small ones (so-called de-normalized numbers) can be written in the form:

```
sign * 1.mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm * 2^eeeee
```

When they are stored, only the `seeeeeeeemmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm` bits are actually stored.

When storing `1.0000000`, the `mmmmmmm` bits are all zero, and the leading `1.` is not stored, since that would be redundant. Therefore the mantissa in the stored bits is all-zeros. The mathematical value of the mantissa though is:

```
mantissa = 1 + 0.mmmmmmm
```

Actually, the exponent is also stored a little differently, to allow for both positive and negative exponents. But that’s outside the scope of this question.

For more information, see the [Wikipedia article on this subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985).